# openxml edition of body

Tags: xml, xslt, openxml

I have the following fragment in an openxml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<!-- ... -->

<a:extLst>
  <a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}">
    <a14:useLocalDpi xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" val="0" />
  </a:ext>
</a:extLst>

<!-- ... -->
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this arises the following error `token '}' expected, 'A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C' found. {28-->A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C<--}` when:
    - loading as an xslt, or
    - edited in visula studio

I just don't know where to dig.
The problem appears when I insert the `xsl:template`.
What does this error mean ?

====== one solution seems to be ========== ==========

```
<a:extLst>
  <xsl:element name="a:ext">
    <xsl:attribute name ="uri">{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}</xsl:attribute>
      <a14:useLocalDpi xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" val="0" />
  </xsl:element>
</a:extLst>
```

but is there something lighter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following, because when you use '{--something--}' it tries to evaluate its content as an xpath:

```
<a:ext uri="{{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}}">
```

Comment: Exactly. You could add that `{{` and `}}` are _escape sequences_ for curly brackets in XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

In XSL, curly brackets within an expression mean "evaluate this" so your solution is probably the best one.